# Why is mysqld always running in the background?

Tags: mysql, process

I have noticed that **mysqld** is always running in the background. It is started at every boot and even after I have killed it, it will restart. I have removed everything related to mysql with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

However, it still shows up in `ps -aux`. What's the meaning of this ?
Also, what does user 27 mean in the output of ps -aux ? I don't remember creating a user 27.

**Explaination** : In fact it was due to a sql docker container running in the background

Comment: @user535733 I tried `which mysqld`, but the output was empty. I also tried `locate mysqld`, and it yielded some mysqldump.cnf files. I am not sure if they are related

Comment: @user535733, any suggestions how to proceed then ?

Comment: Are you running containers? Docker, LXD, etc? Do any of those use msql? If so, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1077562) to include details. Please do not post screenshots of text. Simply copy/paste the text, [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a docker container running that has mysqld in it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1077626)

Comment: @Gordon Bobic, why do you think it is a docker container ?

Comment: @ganto Because a chroot or docker are typical reasons why you would have a process running without a known username for a user ID. I guess it could also be a snap package, not 100% sure about snap.

Comment: @Pilot6 it most certainly provides a rather probable answer, one that is consistent with both symptoms described: no user associated with ID and no mysqld installed on the host.

Comment: @GordanBobic, it is as you said. There was a container running mysql

Comment: @ganto You're welcome. :-)

Comment: I don't even have docker installed, so I wonder why it is always running on my OS (Ubuntu 21.04)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that mysqld is running on my system and eating up over 3GB of RAM.

I began investigating with the following:

```
sudo service --status-all
```

That listed mysql as one of the items running (which I also saw in the System Monitor.

I do not have Docker installed on my system.

I then took a look at the service script:

```
$ cat /etc/init.d/mysql
```

Here's a partial listing for that script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mysql
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
# Description:       Controls the main MySQL database server daemon "mysqld"
#                    and its wrapper script "mysqld_safe".
### END INIT INFO
#
set -e
set -u
${DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG:+ set -v -x}

test -x /usr/bin/mysqld_safe || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

SELF=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd -P)/$(basename $0)
CONF=/etc/mysql/my.cnf
MYADMIN="/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf"

# priority can be overriden and "-s" adds output to stderr
ERR_LOGGER="logger -p daemon.err -t /etc/init.d/mysql -i"

# Safeguard (relative paths, core dumps..)
cd /
umask 077

# mysqladmin likes to read /root/.my.cnf. This is usually not what I want
# as many admins e.g. only store a password without a username there and
# so break my scripts.
export HOME=/etc/mysql/

## Fetch a particular option from mysql's invocation.
#
# Usage: void mysqld_get_param option
mysqld_get_param() {
    /usr/sbin/mysqld --print-defaults \
        | tr " " "\n" \
        | grep -- "--$1" \
        | tail -n 1 \
        | cut -d= -f2
}

## Do some sanity checks before even trying to start mysqld.
sanity_checks() {
  # check for config file
  if [ ! -r /etc/mysql/my.cnf ]; then
    log_warning_msg "$0: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz"
    echo                "WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz" | $ERR_LOGGER
  fi
```

But, where did this come from ?  Did some other thing I installed add mysql to my system?  Nothing that I remember did & also why does it start when I start my machine?

I searched Snaps & Ubuntu software & various other places & it seems that I haven't installed Mysql on my own.

Maybe an installation of Java EE or something? That's probably it.

I ran the following:

```
sudo systemctl --all list-unit-files --type=service
```

I see the following listed for mysql:

```
UNIT_FILE                        STATE           VENDOR PRESET
mysql.service                    enabled         enabled
```

I then needed to disable the service at startup so I ran the following command:

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql.service
```

I ran the check again and I saw that it was indeed disabled:

```
UNIT_FILE                        STATE           VENDOR PRESET
mysql.service                    disabled         enabled
```